# multiple image upload how to make it?

Tags: php, html, mysql, image

I have a code which works fine if I want to upload one image into my MySQL and server.

PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST['btnsave']))
{   foreach($_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){

    $username = $_POST['user_name'];
    $userjob = $_POST['user_job'];
    
    $imgFile = $key.$_FILES['user_image']['name'][$key];
    $tmp_dir = $_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $imgSize = $_FILES['user_image']['size'][$key];
}
    
    if(empty($username)){
        $errMSG = "Please Enter Username.";
    }
    else if(empty($userjob)){
        $errMSG = "Please Enter Your Job Work.";
    }
    else if(empty($imgFile)){
        $errMSG = "Please Select Image File.";
    }
    else
    {
        $upload_dir = 'user_images/'; 
        $imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($imgFile,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); 
        $valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'); 
        $userpic = rand(1000,1000000).".".$imgExt;
        if(in_array($imgExt, $valid_extensions)){           
            if($imgSize < 5000000)              {
                move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir,$upload_dir.$userpic);
            }
            else{
                $errMSG = "Sorry, your file is too large.";
            }
        }
        else{
            $errMSG = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";        
        }
    }
    if(!isset($errMSG))
    {
        $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('INSERT INTO tbl_users(userName,userProfession,userPic) VALUES(:uname, :ujob, :upic)');
        $stmt->bindParam(':uname',$username);
        $stmt->bindParam(':ujob',$userjob);
        $stmt->bindParam(':upic',$userpic);
        
        if($stmt->execute())
        {
            $successMSG = "new record successfully inserted ...";
            header("refresh:5;index.php"); 
        }
        else
        {
            $errMSG = "error while inserting....";
        }
    }
}
```

Html code:

```
    <?php
if(isset($errMSG)){
        ?>
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> <strong><?php echo $errMSG; ?></strong>
        </div>
        <?php
}
else if(isset($successMSG)){
    ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success">
          <strong><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> <?php echo $successMSG; ?></strong>
    </div>
    <?php
}
?>   

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
        
    <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
    
    <tr>
        <td><label class="control-label">Username.</label></td>
        <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="user_name" placeholder="Enter Username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td><label class="control-label">Profession(Job).</label></td>
        <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="user_job" placeholder="Your Profession" value="<?php echo $userjob; ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td><label class="control-label">Profile Img.</label></td>
        <td><input class="input-group" type="file" name="user_image[]" accept="image/*" multiple /></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><button type="submit" name="btnsave" class="btn btn-default">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span> &nbsp; save
        </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    
    </table>
    
</form>
```

How can I make it code to use for multiple upload? For all images which I would upload I would make the same values except 'userPic'- the same name for a file at my server. Can you help me out please?

---

I found one more problem! Maybe you guys can help me?

If I'm trying to upload for example 6 images, one of theme is bigger than maxsize its popups the error but every other files which was uploaded just before it went to upload folder. How to delete this files if i get an error?

second questions is how to resize images? any code?

Answer (score 0):

Put everything inside the **foreach** block.

```
if(isset($_POST['btnsave']))
{   foreach($_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){

$username = $_POST['user_name'];
$userjob = $_POST['user_job'];

$imgFile = $key.$_FILES['user_image']['name'][$key];
$tmp_dir = $_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'][$key];
$imgSize = $_FILES['user_image']['size'][$key];


if(empty($username)){
    $errMSG = "Please Enter Username.";
}
else if(empty($userjob)){
    $errMSG = "Please Enter Your Job Work.";
}
else if(empty($imgFile)){
    $errMSG = "Please Select Image File.";
}
else
{
    $upload_dir = 'user_images/'; 
    $imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($imgFile,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); 
    $valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'); 
    $userpic = rand(1000,1000000).".".$imgExt;
    if(in_array($imgExt, $valid_extensions)){           
        if($imgSize < 5000000)              {
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir,$upload_dir.$userpic);
        }
        else{
            $errMSG = "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        }
    }
    else{
        $errMSG = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";        
    }
}
if(!isset($errMSG))
{
    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('INSERT INTO tbl_users(userName,userProfession,userPic) VALUES(:uname, :ujob, :upic)');
    $stmt->bindParam(':uname',$username);
    $stmt->bindParam(':ujob',$userjob);
    $stmt->bindParam(':upic',$userpic);

    if($stmt->execute())
    {
        $successMSG = "new record succesfully inserted ...";
        header("refresh:5;index.php"); 
    }
    else
    {
        $errMSG = "error while inserting....";
    }
}
}}
```

Comment: I have one more question: is it possible to also resize images if i'm usuing multiple upload? how to do that?

Comment: @user3357181  use ImageMagick or GD library to resize images.